# How do I join the output meshes of the Cell Fracture addon?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I have a simple, unsubdivided plane mesh with a particle system that I want to apply Cell Fracture on, following this step-by-step guide: http://blendersushi.blogspot.de/2012/07/vfx-voronoi-cage.html

But I'm stuck at the part where the author writes

> For the purpose of creating Voronoi Cage, I actually just need the "wireframe edges", so I join the Shards back into a single mesh (CTRL+J).

, since there is nothing to join.

Here's a screenshot of my Cell Fracture settings:
[image: Screenshot of plane before applying Cell Fracture]

And here's what Blender looks like after applying Cell Fracture:
[image: Screenshot of plane after applying Cell Fracture]

Selecting the original mesh named "Plane" and hitting Ctrl+J yields "No mesh data to join", while selecting any of the new "Plane_cell*" meshes and hitting Ctrl+J does nothing, not even displaying some error message.

I'm certain that I'm missing something crucial, but I can't figure out what.

(Sorry for the uninspired tag choices, no other tags looked appropriate.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fractured objects are on the second layer. The original object is kept unmodified on the first layer.

The following is a good, detailed video tutorial on the subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTq9sLQOiVs